# App crashes on SocketTimeoutException in Android

Tags: android, connection-timeout, socket-timeout-exception

I have implemented `AsyncTask` in `Activity` properly (based on many sources).

Also I have investigated `SocketTimeoutException` and catche exception as you can see in the code below.

Anyway when I stop `webapi` and simulate `SocketTimeoutException` the app crashes immediately. (Please, check the error's message.)

Debuging code goes to `IOException` and then I see the error's message and app restarts.

**Code**

```
private class FetchHauls extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                AppSettings.ComplexPreferences complexPreferences = AppSettings.ComplexPreferences.getComplexPreferences(context, "App_Settings", 0);
                AppSettings appSettings = complexPreferences.getObject("App_Settings", AppSettings.class);
                if (appSettings != null) {
                    String uri = appSettings.getIpAddress() + "/api/Version1/GetGrandTotalStats";

                    GrandTotalStatsRequest grandTotalStatsRequest = new GrandTotalStatsRequest();
                    Date d = new Date();
                    CharSequence timeOfRequest = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", d.getTime()); 
                    grandTotalStatsRequest.AtTime = timeOfRequest.toString();
                    grandTotalStatsRequest.DeviceID = appSettings.getDeviceID();

                    grandTotalStatsRequest.DeviceSerialNumber = appSettings.getSerialNumber();

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(grandTotalStatsRequest);

                    //Connect
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(55000);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    //Write
                    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    writer.write(json);
                    writer.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    String result = null;
                    //Read
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                        String l = null;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((l = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(l);
                        }

                        bufferedReader.close();

                        result = sb.toString();
                    }

                    return result;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            if (isCancelled()) {
                return;
            }

            swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            taskFetchHauls = null;
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) return;

            try {
                // Some code...

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(PAGE_TITLE, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /172.15.15.2 (port 1067) after 60000ms
                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
                        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
                        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                        at android.apps.ktk.company.gpsmegatracker.Activities.GrandStatActivity$FetchHauls.doInBackground(GrandStatActivity.java:291)
                        at android.apps.ktk.company.gpsmegatracker.Activities.GrandStatActivity$FetchHauls.doInBackground(GrandStatActivity.java:259)
                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8617', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Well you aren't explicitly catching `SocketTimeoutException`, but this is a desendant of `IOException`, which are you are catching (but doing nothing).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hi Tim! Yes, when I try to add another `SocketTimeoutException catch` then Android Studio says that is redundant catch.

Comment: That's because you are adding it in the wrong place.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OK, Tim. Please, give me another solution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `SocketTimeoutException` would propagate from your code as posted. Are you sure that's not just something logging the exception, which you then catch and ignore, and then something else causes the crash?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Hi bro! I fixed the error using `Tim Biegeleisen` solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to catch a `SocketTimeoutException`, then you should use the following pattern.  Note carefully that we catch exceptions from most *specific* to most *general*.  Because `SocketTimeoutException` is a child of `IOException`, we catch the former first.  Using the reverse order will result in the error you were seeing.  Finally, we catch general `Exception` last.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        // make the async call

    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
        // display timeout alert to user
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // handle general IO error
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // just in case you missed anything else
    }
    finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```